# Layout Nodes - Space Between Nodes?

Tags: vis.js

I'm visualizing a network with **VisJS**, and using the default layout with physics enabled.  When nodes are added, a layout is done and the nodes are placed on the canvas.  However, some of my nodes are quite large.  Is there a way to force the amount of space that is left between nodes?

I've tried setting the size of the node, which doesn't seem to have an effect.  The shape of the node is **"square"**.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out, I was missing physics options for the engine I was using, in particular "avoidOverlap".